# XSSFWorksheet duplicates the output after closing the file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I started working with Apache poi just recently. What I'm trying to do:

My method receives a HashMap, with the key being a long Vendor (a class I've created to represent a customer of my company) ID, and the value being the Vendor object itself.
My goal is to use the boolean attribute 'managed' in the Vendor object, and output into one file the list of managed Vendors (the ones that have 'true' in 'managed') and then another one for the unmanaged. Here's my code:

```
 public static void loadVendorsIntoFile(XSSFWorkbook workbook, HashMap<Long,Vendor> vendors, boolean managed){

    XSSFSheet vendorsSheet = workbook.createSheet("Vendors");
    int rowNum = 1;
    Row row = vendorsSheet.createRow(0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("vendor_id");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("num_items");
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("vendor_username");
    row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Segment");
    row.createCell(4).setCellValue("AM");
    for (long vendor : vendors.keySet()){
        if (vendors.get(vendor) != null && vendors.get(vendor).getIfManaged() == managed){
            row = vendorsSheet.createRow(rowNum);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(vendors.get(vendor).getVendorId());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(vendors.get(vendor).getCountItems());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(vendors.get(vendor).getVendorName());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(vendors.get(vendor).getSegment());
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(vendors.get(vendor).getAccountManager());
            rowNum++;
        }
    }
}

public static void topvendorsOutput (HashMap<Long,Vendor> vendors) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException{
    XSSFWorkbook managedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    loadVendorsIntoFile(managedWorkbook,vendors,true);
    OutputStream outManaged = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\managed_out.xlsx");
    managedWorkbook.write(outManaged);
    outManaged.close();

    XSSFWorkbook nonManagedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    loadVendorsIntoFile(nonManagedWorkbook,vendors,false);

    OutputStream outNonManaged = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out.xlsx");
    managedWorkbook.write(outNonManaged);
    outNonManaged.close();

}
```

However, for some reason I get two files with the same info - both show only managed Vendors. I've been testing (printing to the console) and I see that in the second call to loadVendorsIntoFile(), the unmanaged Vendors are really being printed when the loop runs - but for some reason the what is written to the second file is the info that should come only from the first call (and first file) to the method.
Also, the second call (which creates the second file) comes out with corruption problems, excel warns me that it has "found problems with the content" and needs to restore it.
I guess I'm doing something wrong here. 
So in short - the first file is OK, the second one isn't.

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Your code snipped shows you writing to the same file each time!

Comment: I edited the code - that was not the problem. I modified the code for privacy reasons, and forgot to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, we see a few problems:

```
XSSFWorkbook managedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
loadVendorsIntoFile(managedWorkbook,vendors,true);
OutputStream outManaged = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out.xlsx");
managedWorkbook.write(outManaged);
outManaged.close();
```

This writes `managedWorkbook` into `C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out.xlsx`

```
XSSFWorkbook nonManagedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
loadVendorsIntoFile(nonManagedWorkbook,vendors,false);

OutputStream outNonManaged = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out.xlsx");
managedWorkbook.write(outNonManaged);
outNonManaged.close();
```

This also writes `managedWorkbook` into `C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out.xlsx` !

I suspect that you meant that last bit to instead be something like:

```
OutputStream outNonManaged = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\unmanaged_out2.xlsx");
nonManagedWorkbook.write(outNonManaged);
outNonManaged.close();
```

Note how the changed snippet both writes into a different file, and importantly, writes out the second workbook you created, rather than outputting the first one twice!

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. I edited my question - it's a mistake while I copied the code here, my actual code had 2 different paths, with 2 different files generating in different places, but with the same content. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your new code still writes the same workbook twice, which is your main problem, and covered in the above answer